# SQL query for different values of member

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement, in which if a member has value equal to 0 then remove all the values related to that member.

```
Eg MemberID   Value
      1        0
      1        123
      2        3
      3        4
      3        0
```

Then in result i should only get MemberID 2. For other members it has value with 0

Comment: You mean delete those records from table?

Comment: _...has value greater than 0 or equal to 0 then remove all the values..._ This would remove all the values from your sample table.

Comment: Do you mean delete all like `MemberID` occurrences if a `MemberID` has a `value` of `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a subquery:

```
delete from table1 t1
where t1.MemberId in (select t2.MemberId from table1 t2 where t2.value=0)
```

Comment: This is incorrect as the logic is to remove all the records where value is 0 and other related (same id) records as well.

Comment: Hey Masum7 - you are correct with the logic, just need alias you can edit so that I can remove the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
delete from tbl 
where MemberID in (select MemberID from tbl b where b.Value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select those records, you can use:

```
SELECT MemberID,SUM(CASE WHEN Value=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Value=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5127d/11) (Using different sample data with negative values)

To delete those records from table,

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE MemberID NOT IN
(SELECT MemberID
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Value=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0)
```

Comment: As per the sample data the `MemberID=2`  should appear in result, even if it is positive, just reversing the data to negative value is not correct answer..

Comment: @Murtaza: My answer was correct for the original question (OP had asked to delete records of members having 0 or greater value. Thant is why I used a record with negative value). Please visit previous edits of the question. Since my answer doesn't fit for the current question, I have updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete every members having more than one `value >= 0`, here is your query:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE MemberID IN (SELECT T.MemberID
                   FROM yourTable T
                   WHERE T.Value >= 0
                   GROUP BY T.MemberID
                   HAVING COUNT(T.Value) > 1)
```

If you want to delete every members having at least one `value = 0`, here is the query:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE MemberID IN (SELECT T.MemberID
                   FROM yourTable T
                   WHERE T.Value = 0)
```

Hope this will help.